# Access - Excluding first column from lookup values

Tags: ms-access, lookup

I have this database and a field's lookup is set to comboBox with 'bound column' to 2 and 'column count' to 2.. My row source's first column is ID (AutoNumber), and my second column is Name(Text). When I go to Datasheet View and select a value it displays ID column value.

How to make it display a Name column value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just managed it in one way. In Design View, from dropdown list of your field (the one with lookup comboBox) select Lookup wizard.. Then go through the wizard, and that's it. However, I'm not sure how the wizard solves it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic ways to achieve this manually. This has to do with updating properties of the combo box. The particular properties are listed under Data or Format.

Return the ID as the first column, set the column count to 2, set the data bound to column 1, and define column widths with the first width = 0. Something like, 0";2" This way technically both columns display, but the first one has 0 width.

Or my preferance

Return the ID as the second column. Set the column count to 1 and bind the value to column 2. Doing this only the first column will display, but the 2nd column will be the value. The reason I prefer this method is that you can let Access determine the size of the drop-down column instead of defining it.

Comment: I would *never* use your second method because the value of the combo is then the text portion, not the id, so it is no longer suitable for queries because you must refer to a column number to get the relevant ID.

Comment: Not so, you just have to bind the second column instead of the first. I assure you it works as expected.

Comment: Hmm, it seems it is prejudice on my part. It just does not feel right, but I cannot think why at the moment :)

Comment: Don't feel bad. Basically everyone recommends doing it the first way. In fact, I do not believe I've ever seen anyone say you can do it the way that I do. I just don't like it do to typical way because it seems messier. I guess it's a personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Select the column1, column2, column1(again)
Set width = 0.01;.5;.5
column1 is not visible, but is the value you want in your field

Comment: Set Column Count = 3